# Automatically publish plugin after installation

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, plugin

I've created a couple of small plugins that I install on most of my websites. But new plugins are (fortunately) disabled by default when installed. I know it's only a couple of clicks to enable the plugin, but is it possible to make my plugin enable itself once the installation is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is creating an install script that executes a `postflight` function. This function is built into Joomla and will get executed after the extension has installed.

You could use something like this:

```
function postflight($type, $parent)
{
    // We only need to perform this if the extension is being installed, not updated
    if (strtolower($type) === 'install') 
    {       
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('enabled') . ' = 1',
            $db->quoteName('ordering') . ' = 9999'
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote('plg_myplugin'), 
            $db->quoteName('type') . ' = ' . $db->quote('plugin')
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);   
        $db->execute();     
    }
}
```

For more information on the script file, have a read of the Joomla Documentation:

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_(Script.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe that `1` and `9999` are integers and there is no need for type casting ;)

Comment: @Farahmand - It can be used but I suppose not a major requirement. I actually asked a question about this a while back: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/database-query-where-value-is-a-number .. not sure why using type casting deserves a downvote though as the concept/approach is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plugin like this:

```
class plgExtensionEnableMyPlugins extends JPlugin
{
    public function onExtensionAfterInstall($installer, $eid)
    {
        if ($eid)
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $db->setQuery("UPDATE #__extensions SET `enabled` = 1 WHERE `extension_id` = $eid AND `type` = 'plugin'");
            $db->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Install and enable the above plugin before installing your plugins.

Comment: You are suggesting using an additional plugin to perform this action? So what if I'm a user downloading @johan's plugin and I expect it to auto publish? Will he expect me to install this plugin you mentioned before downloading his?

Comment: @Lodder, The question is about a "couple" of plugins that created by johan and he wants to install on "his" websites. If he had said the conditions you mentioned, my answer was something else ;)

Comment: @Farahmand, I do use the plugins mostly on sites I develop, but still, installing and enabling a plugin in order to auto-enable a couple of others seems a little overkill. But thanks for the code.

Comment: @johanpw, No problem. Personally I prefer to use a plugin instead of to write `postflight` functions for all of my plugins. I believe that it's not an overkill. I can uninstall/disable the plugin as soon as I installed all of my plugins. Hope this helps people with similar case.