# Automatically display/render module upon installation

Tags: module-display

Can you help please?

I've build a simple module which displays two 'back to top of page' arrows, one bottom left and the other bottom right. It works well if inside an existing template module position or in the component area using {loadmodule mod_backtotop}.  However, I want to be able to automatically display the module as soon as it's installed, either without the need for a module position or maybe create a new module position upon installation?

I hope this makes sense, I'm not sure if I've explained it well.

Any help gratefully received.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Lodder this is the code I used.  Hopefully this will help others.

```
    if (strtolower($type) === 'install') 
    {       
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('position') . ' = ' . $db->quote('backtotop'),
            $db->quoteName('showtitle') . ' = 0',
            $db->quoteName('published') . ' = 1'
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('module') . ' = ' . $db->quote('mod_backtotop')
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__modules'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);   
        $db->execute();     
    }
```

Comment: You can use this as a starting point: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4593/168 It's specifically for plugins, but you can adapt it for a module

Comment: Thank you @Lodder.  I've used your link to automatically publish my module and assign it to position 'backtotop', it works perfectly.  However, because the position 'backtotop' doesn't exist in my template how do I get the module to actually display/render please?  I've seen examples of how to render modules but I'm not sure where the code should go.

Comment: Please update your original question with any updates

Comment: As you can see my module now automatically publishes, but, to finalise it and I've searched a lot for this but can't find a solution, is there a way to automatically make the module's 'Module Assignment' be 'On all pages' please?  When it installs it defaults to 'No pages'.

Comment: I believe that will need to be done in a different database table.

Comment: Thank you very much  for all your help @Lodder, you've been a great help yet again.